# enumerate a block in different frames

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I do have 3 blocks in 3 differents frames but i want to enumerate them

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
   \begin{document}
 ...
   \begin{frame}{Modèle Vue Contrôleur}
       \begin{block}{Le Modèle}%num 1
       \end{block}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}{Modèle Vue Contrôleur}
       \begin{block}{La Vue}%num 2
       \end{block}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

how can I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It is recommended that put a minimal working example which begin with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` not a fragment of code.  
What do you mean with enumerate block?

Comment: sorry, I'm begginer on latex, i have a section that contains 3 points, i put each point in a block, i want to enumerate them if possible, and i can't justify my paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup your own counter like this:

```
\newcounter{bcounter}
\newcommand{\bitem}{\stepcounter{bcounter}\arabic{bcounter}. }
```

and then invoke each block with the `\bitem` command to enumerate the blocks automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}   
   \newcounter{bcounter}
   \newcommand{\bitem}{\stepcounter{bcounter}\arabic{bcounter}. }

   \begin{frame}{Modèle Vue Contrôleur}
       \begin{block}{\bitem Le Modèle}%num 1
       \end{block}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}{Modèle Vue Contrôleur}
       \begin{block}{\bitem La Vue}%num 2
       \end{block}
   \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The block not the frame !?